# Xcode showing duplicate schemes for same target when using shared scheme

Tags: xcode

We are trying to include some pre-build script in Xcode. So to make it available to all, we are marking the target Xcode scheme as "Shared" and we are committing shared Xcode scheme to git repository. Now the problem is that when ever some one pulls the code they are seeing both shared scheme as well as the Xcode generated user specific schemes for the same target, resulting in 2 schemes for the same target. So is there any way to disable auto creation of scheme for specific target? We see that there is one "Auto Create schemes" check box. But unchecking this will disable it for all the targets? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.